# Is every (possibly infinite) sum of cardinal numbers defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Hrbacek and Jech gives the following definition of cardinal addition:
[image]

My question is: given an indexed system of cardinals $\left \langle \kappa_{i} |i\in I \right \rangle$ does there exist a system $\left \langle A_{i} |i\in I \right \rangle$ of mutually disjoint sets such that $|A_{i}|=\kappa_{i}$ for all $i \in I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Just let $A_i=\{i\}\times \kappa_i$, for instance.